# Why won't redshift accept my fixedwidth text file

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2008-r2, streamwriter

I am reading a `varchar(500)` column from a SQL Server 2008 R2 database to import into Redshift via a fixedwidth text file.

To pull down the record into a fixed width file, I started out by using a `StringBuilder` to write out a block of text at a time. I was using `AppendFormat` and the alignment specifier to align the different records. At certain points, once every 400k lines, I would write the contents of `StringBuilder` into a `StreamWriter` to write to disk.

I noticed that there was an issue with text when I tried loading the files into Redshift, the upload into Reshift failed due to extra columns, (there were more columns than my fixed width specification accommodated for).

When I tested the `StringBuilder` against a regular string, the widths match what I intended them to match, 500 characters.

The discrepancy came when I tried writing my records to disk. I kept getting the same issue when I wrote the aforementioned database column to disk using `WriteLineformat` the `StreamWriter` object.

The collation on the database is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. I understand that strings from the database get converted the database collation to UTF-16. I think there is no problem there, as stated from the test I performed above. I think the issue I'm having is from taking the string in UTF-16 form and writing them to disk using `StreamWriter`.

I can expect any type of character from the database field, except for a newline or carriage return.  I'm pretty confident that white space is trimmed before being pushed into the database column using a combination of the TSQL functions `Ltrim` and `Rtrim`.

Edit: Following is the code I use in Powershell

```
$dw = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("<connection string details>")
$dw.open()
$reader = (new-object System.Data.SqlClient.Sqlcommand("select email from emails",$dw)).ExecuteReader()
$writer = new-object system.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Emails.txt",[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
while($reader.read())
{
    $writer.writelineformat("{0,-500}",$reader["email"])
}
$writer.close()
$reader.close()
```

Obviously I'm not going to give you the details of my connection string or my table naming convention.

Edit:  I'm including the AWS Redshift article that explains that data can only be imported into Redshift using UTF-8 encoding.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_preparing-input-data.html

Edit: I was able to get a sample of the outputted file through

```
get-content -encoding utf8
```

The content inside of the file is definitely UTF-8 proper.  All of the line endings within.  It's seems like my main issue is with Redshift taking multi-byte characters for fixed width files.

Comment: Please show your code. We don't guess about how to fix things without seeing what's broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so that anyone seeing this understands.  My problem is really with redshift.  One thing I have noticed is that the service seems to have processing issues with fixedwidth files.  This seems to be specific to Amazon, since the underlying system that runs Redshift is ParAccel.  I had issues in the past with Fixedwidth files.  I have been able to confirm that there is an issue with Redshift accepting multi-byte characters within fixedwidth version of the S3 Copy command.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that the issue is caused by the fact that [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtbhzte9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) by default uses UTF-8 so in some instances you will get double byte characters as utf-8 is variable width.

Try using [unicode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.unicodeencoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which will match your database encoding, [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3aadshsx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has an overload which supports encoding.

Comment: I appreciate the advice David.  I just pulled up the Documentation from AWS Redshift, and they only support loading files into databases with text that is using a UTF-8 collation.  I'm am pretty sure you are correct in that using unicode (I believe .Net refers to UTF-16) will have no issues since there would not be any conversion involved.  Thanks though.